# Firebase orderByChild startAt endAt and then equalTo specific name

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Trying to grab data from custom date range and with specific location name "California".

Currently grabbing the date range successfully: but result returns all locations. I'm not sure where to put `equalTo`.

```
database.ref('/app/shows').orderByChild('timerange/start').startAt(myStartDate).endAt(myEndDate).once('value', function (snapshot) {
    // stuff
})
```

my json:

```
"shows" : {
  "show-15039414000001503945000000" : {
    "timerange" : {
      "end" : 1503945000000,
      "start" : 1503941400000
    },
    "location" : "California"
  },
  "show-15040998000001504101600000" : {
    "timerange" : {
      "end" : 1504101600000,
      "start" : 1504099800000
    },
    "location" : "San Diego"
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property, so you cannot filter on both `start` and `location`. But you may be able to combine the values into a single synthetic property, e.g. `"location_start": "California_ 1503941400000"`. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks a lot.